# Mysql search two tables

Tags: mysql

My cats layout:

| ID | cat_name | main_cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | vehicles | 0 |
| 2 | bikes | 1 |
| 3 | cars | 1 |
| 4 | Real estate | 0 |
| 5 | Condo's | 4 |

My Posts layout:

| ID | ad_title | ad_price | ad_sub_cat | some more |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test title | 200 | 3 | etc: |

My Posts attributes:

| ID | ad_id | att_cat | ad_att |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 5000km |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2009 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | Toyota |

Okay as you can see this is a clean and simple database layout users can post different types of posts from houses to cars etc.. that's why we have a `posts_attributes` table that is linked to the type of category so that we can display it like this

Km: 5000km |
Year: 2009 |
Brand: Toyota

I can't think of a better database schema but we lead into a problem. i was building the search page and while i was doing the advanced filter I realized i don't fully know how to search for the km or the type of brand or the year i know about `INNER JOIN` but i am not sure how to search this kind of data is it possible for anyone to help me understand how i can search these two tables for the type of brand or km range etc...

here is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_sub_cat` = ? 
AND `ad_brand` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `ad_price` <= ?
```

If this post needs improvement etc. please tell me and i will fix anything or clarify what you are asking :) have a nice day

Comment: you can have two columns in post attributes, 1. post_attribute_key 2. post_attribute_value. this way you can filter on the post_attribute_key for KM or brand

Comment: @sid I was thinkings the same thing but I thought let me rather ask on here where some more exp devs can help me - thanks for the info i will wait to see if any other answers come then i will use your way :) have a good day buddy

Comment: @sid for clarification by `post_attribute_key` you mean like any one with the value of lets say 9 is a Brand and if its a value of 6 its a km etc..

Comment: yeah brand would be key like Adidas and value would be its shoes, this will let you search for adidas items by its key

Comment: @sid i don't understand sorry if i get this wrong post_attribute_key will be the value the user entered like Toyota or ford?

Comment: can you maybe write this in a answer for me so that i can see your table layout(if you don;t mind )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB schema you've opted for is quite right. This is referred as storing **MetaData**, where the child table has a foreign key linked to the parent table's id and 2 columns, conventionally named with **meta_key** and another with **meta_value**.

meta_key: This column indicates what it holds, simple. Could be anything like *post_views*, *post_bg_color*, *post_template* and so on.

meta_value: For *post_views* the value would be 1,20,000,  *post_bg_color* would be *red*, *post_template* would be just *full_layout*

You can extend this to whatever extent you want beyond just storing *post* related values.

Wordpress already uses this DB structure and is widely used by several companies.

Refs:

1. https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description
2. https://wp-staging.com/docs/the-wordpress-database-structure/
3. https://wp-staging.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Wordpress_database_structure.png
4. https://blogvault.net/wordpress-database-schema/

Comment: Thanks, mate I understand now so key will be Brand and value will be Toyota or Ford and if its km the key will be kilometers and value will be 1000km instead of having it be words can I make an extra table called att_words and instead of having brand it will be a 1 which will then link to the word brand

Comment: do you mean to associate it with FK id in another table? might be a bit complex to fetch relations, but go ahead if you're ok with it. I'd simply

Comment: yes i do think it might be a bit complex but won't that stop data replication in the database like what if two posts has the same FK of `Brand` then that will be easier to just put it as a number rather than a bunch of letters

Comment: yes, keeping that pov in mind, its correct.